# Indexing Multidimensional Arrays/Matrices: Beginner's R

Tags: r, multidimensional-array, indexing

I am using rem.dyad from the package 'relevent' to run social network models (my first experience with R). I have multiple covariates that I have encoded as matrices. The package documentation states that one needs to "create a pxnxn array, whose first dimension indexes the covariate matrices". The network that I am working with consists of 18 actors so there are 4  18x18 matrices. I have combined them into a multidimensional matrix but I am unsure how to index them and then combine this index matrix into the same object as the other matrices.

I realise this is a newbie question but I haven't managed to find a solution. I have had no luck in my searches for an easy solution and would appreciate any advice or links to resources.

Thanks.

Comment: @ ily1: did the answer solve your problem. Your feedback will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Following code may be of help:

```
> mmlist = list()
> for(i in 1:3) mmlist[[i]]=matrix(1:12, nrow=3)
> mmlist
[[1]]
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
[1,]    1    4    7   10
[2,]    2    5    8   11
[3,]    3    6    9   12

[[2]]
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
[1,]    1    4    7   10
[2,]    2    5    8   11
[3,]    3    6    9   12

[[3]]
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
[1,]    1    4    7   10
[2,]    2    5    8   11
[3,]    3    6    9   12



> mmlist[[1]]
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
[1,]    1    4    7   10
[2,]    2    5    8   11
[3,]    3    6    9   12
> mmlist[[2]]
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
[1,]    1    4    7   10
[2,]    2    5    8   11
[3,]    3    6    9   12
```